# Calculate target Pixels from given Angle

Tags: java, android, canvas, drawing, pixel

What i want :

[image]
I am using Orientation Sensor to get Azmuth value (Angle). i am also taking starting point from user and draw a circle. Now i want to draw next pixel on the point where the user is heading considering that one step is equal to 30 pixels.

As user starts walking i want to draw circles of user current position on the image of floor plan inserted on screen. I can't use GPS for this solution due to certain reasons.

Here are steps i am performing :

1. Get current user direction in angles from Orientation sensor.
2. User will touch on screen to draw starting point on image.
3. As user starts walking it will draw points on the image relative to user's real world direction like i showed in above image. How can i certainly achieve this given only starting point(pixelX,pixelY) and start angle of user and current angle where he just faced.

What we have achieved so far :
We can draw straight lines on 4 angles i.e 0 , 90,180 and 270 by just adding and subtracting pixels to current pixels.

newAzimuth is current angle of user direction

```
           if (newAzimuth >= 45 && newAzimuth <= 135) {
                startX = startX + oneStepPixelsWidth;
            mScreenRotationTextView.setText("You turned (Right)");
            } else if (newAzimuth > 135 && newAzimuth <= 225) {
            mScreenRotationTextVniew.setText("You turned (Back)");
                startY = startY + oneStepPixelsHeight;
            } else if (newAzimuth > 225 && newAzimuth <= 315) {
            mScreenRotationTextView.setText("You turned (Left)");
                startX = startX - oneStepPixelsWidth;
            } else if (newAzimuth > 315 || newAzimuth < 45) {
            mScreenRotationTextView.setText("You turned (Front)");
                startY = startY - oneStepPixelsHeight;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that calculated angles are:

[image]

Here's the equations for that.

```
X=distance*cos(angle)
Y=distance*sin(angle)
```

In your case distance will always be 30 pixel

so (30Cos(Angle),30Sin(Angle)) will give you your location.

To adjust your calculated angle to work you can rotate them with those formulas;

```
adjustedX = x cos(angle) − y sin(angle)
adjustedY = y cos(angle) + x sin(angle)
```

By exemple if the angle calculated are like this:

[image]

Then you will need to;

1. Rotate 90 degree right or 270 degree left.
2. Translate.
3. Rotate 270 degree right or 90 degree left.

```java
 private Pair<Double, Double> getPositionOf(Pair<Double, Double> lastPosition, double angle, int distance, int angleAdjustment)
    {
        final Pair<Double, Double> rotatedLeftPosition = rotateLeft(lastPosition, 360 - angleAdjustment);
        final Pair<Double, Double> translatedLocation = applyTranslationTo(rotatedLeftPosition, angle, distance);
        return rotateLeft(translatedLocation, angleAdjustment);
    }

    private Pair<Double, Double> rotateLeft(Pair<Double, Double> position, double degreeAngle)
    {
        double x = position.first;
        double y = position.second;

        double adjustedX = (x * Math.cos(degreeAngle)) - (y * Math.sin(degreeAngle));
        double adjustedY = (y * Math.cos(degreeAngle)) + (x * Math.sin(degreeAngle));
        return new Pair<>(adjustedX, adjustedY);
    }

    @NotNull
    private Pair<Double, Double> applyTranslationTo(final Pair<Double, Double> position, final double angle, final int distance)
    {
        double x = distance * Math.cos(angle);
        double y = distance * Math.sin(angle);
        return new Pair<>(position.first + x, position.second + y);
    }
```

Where angleAdjustment will be 90

Comment: the new pixel values are not in a straight line when i was walking straight with angle of about 0-20 . the new pixel values were plotted around my current position

Comment: does your angle is in radian or degree ?

Comment: its in Degree. its range is 0-360

Comment: Juste to be sure when the device give you the angle of zero the user is pointing to the right of you plan ?

Comment: No. when angle is zero we need to plot in front of user. when angle is 90 its right side of user. 180 will be when it has turned around. and 270 will be left.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203247/discussion-between-jcdecary-and-zaeem-sattar).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was almost 80% right in terms of our scenario. The only changes that we have done are these:
1- We added new angle to the previous angle
2- we were plotting values directly coming from your given formula but it should be added after the calculations.

Comment: glad i could help